# xhtml <object> problem with explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, svg

I have an html page with this code

```
<object data="ciao.xhtml" width="100%" height="100%"
type="application/xhtml+xml">
</object>
```

ciao.xhtml contain a well formed xhtml with svg embedded.

It work well in chrome and firefox but when i test it on explorer i don't see enything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer, except version 9 (which isn't out) and versions with third party plugins (which are rare) doesn't support XHTML (text/html content with an XHTML Doctype doesn't count) or SVG.

If you want this to work then you need to look at providing alternative content for IE 8 and lower, e.g. an iframe containing an HTML document with embedded VML.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type attribute to `type="image/svg+xml"` and the file name extension to `.svg` as the [SVG recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#MIMEType) says.